# Custom tags work every other time django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

***I did the calf's ear.  forgive me for asking this stupid question.***

***The error has been found, I try to load the function with my load when it's not the function that is loaded but the py file.**

***update add directory tree**

I'm in total misunderstanding, I created custom tags for my project. I had a hard time to get them accepted by django (I had to reboot my local server several times) finally it worked here I save a new custom tag, but I can't load it in django, it tells me that the tag doesn't exist. I restarted several times. I even made a copy of my previous code by simply changing the name of the function but I can't get django to take it, it tells me that it doesn't exist... 
Thank you in advance :)

in application > templatetags with init file etc...

**in template use :**

`{% load tags_blog tags_files %}` work

`{% load background_image %}` doesn't work The first two custom tags work

**Work tag loaded in django :(base.html)**

```
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag()
def news_archive_date_blog():
    list_all_year = New.all_year_post()
    if len(list_all_year) > 1:
        list_all_year.remove(timezone.now().year)
        return list_all_year

@register.simple_tag()
def rallies_archive_date_blog():
    list_all_year = Rally.all_year_post()
    if len(list_all_year) > 1:
        list_all_year.remove(timezone.now().year)
        return list_all_year
```

**no work (TemplateSyntaxError at /'background_image' is not a registered tag library.)(base.html)**

```
@register.simple_tag()
def background_image():
    list_all_year = Rally.all_year_post()
    if len(list_all_year) > 1:
        list_all_year.remove(timezone.now().year)
        return list_all_year
```

- bmvt:

  - bmvt
  - blog:

    - templatetags

      - init
      - tags_blogs
    - models

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
>   django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'backgroundimage' is
>   not a registered tag library. Must be one of: account admin_list
>   admin_modify admin_static admin_urls cache compress crispy_forms_field
>   crispy_forms_filters crispy_forms_tags crispy_forms_utils
>   debugger_tags highlighting hitcount_tags i18n indent_text l10n log pwa
>   rest_framework socialaccount solo_tags static staticfiles syntax_color
>   tags_blog tags_files truncate_letters tz widont
>
> Traceback (most recent call last) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py",
>   line 1021, in find_library return parser.libraries[name] During
>   handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py",
>   line 65, in **call** return self.application(environ, start_response)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py",
>   line 141, in **call** response = self.get_response(request) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 75, in get_response response = self._middleware_chain(request)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 36, in inner response = response_for_exception(request, exc) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 90, in response_for_exception response =
>   handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()),
>   sys.exc_info()) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception return
>   debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 37, in null_technical_500_response six.reraise(exc_type,
>   exc_value, tb) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py",
>   line 695, in reraise raise value.with_traceback(tb) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 34, in inner response = get_response(request) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 145, in _get_response response =
>   self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 143, in _get_response response = response.render() File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py",
>   line 106, in render self.content = self.rendered_content File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py",
>   line 81, in rendered_content template =
>   self.resolve_template(self.template_name) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py",
>   line 63, in resolve_template return select_template(template,
>   using=self.using) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py",
>   line 42, in select_template return engine.get_template(template_name)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py",
>   line 34, in get_template return
>   Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py",
>   line 143, in get_template template, origin =
>   self.find_template(template_name) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py",
>   line 125, in find_template template = loader.get_template(name,
>   skip=skip) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py",
>   line 30, in get_template contents, origin, origin.template_name,
>   self.engine, File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line
>   156, in **init** self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist() File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line
>   194, in compile_nodelist return parser.parse() File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line
>   478, in parse raise self.error(token, e) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line
>   476, in parse compiled_result = compile_func(self, token) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py",
>   line 266, in do_extends nodelist = parser.parse() File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line
>   478, in parse raise self.error(token, e) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line
>   476, in parse compiled_result = compile_func(self, token) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py",
>   line 1078, in load lib = find_library(parser, name) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py",
>   line 1025, in find_library name, "\n".join(sorted(parser.libraries)),
>   django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'backgroundimage' is
>   not a registered tag library. Must be one of: account admin_list
>   admin_modify admin_static admin_urls cache compress crispy_forms_field
>   crispy_forms_filters crispy_forms_tags crispy_forms_utils
>   debugger_tags highlighting hitcount_tags i18n indent_text l10n log pwa
>   rest_framework socialaccount solo_tags static staticfiles syntax_color
>   tags_blog tags_files truncate_letters tz widont

Comment: You should include where exactly the files with the templatetags code are located in relation to your apps, your `INSTALLED_APPS`, name of the files etc. Django works based on convention (rather then configuration), so file location and naming is essential.

Comment: @Risadinha all my applications are well loaded in installed app :)

`INSTALLED_APPS = [
"bmvt.blog.apps.BlogConfig",
    "bmvt.files.apps.FilesConfig",
    "bmvt.agenda.apps.AgendaConfig",
    "bmvt.advertisement.apps.AdvertisementConfig"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have someone who made me understand my totally stupid mistake, I'm trying to use the {% load %} tag on a function when it's the .py file that's loaded so I have to load the file once and use the tags afterwards.